# Ubuntu 12.10 not seeing 13.04 update?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-13.04

A couple days ago, without realizing it, I installed and configured Ubuntu 12.10 only to find out that 13.04 was going to be/has been released.

I tried all the usual tricks to get the update, from `update-manager -d` to `apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` this is of course after doing `sudo -i`.

I have even tried the normal way, through the update manager - nope. My system is all up to date yet I am running 12.10.

I have a work machine that was upgraded yesterday via the `update-manager` command.

thoughts?

Comment: What makes you think you are still running 12.10? What was the output of the commands you tried? What do you mean by "nope"? What is the output of `lsb_release -r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1327424

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Please backup your data before you do that - whenever I did this I almost ALWAYS had issues. It was never anything critical but usually it was like an icon package that didn't get installed.

Answer (score 0):

Im taking a guess here as I dont use Ububtu.  I had a similar issue with Mint a while ago, where there was no upgrade from 13 to 14, they wanted you to do a fresh install.  There were some workarounds, but I figured better safe than sorry.  I did come across this [article](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12.04-lts-precise-pangolin-to-12.10-quantal-quetzal-desktop-and-server) for Ubuntu, thay may be useful to you.  Perhaps following the steps will allow you to upgrade.  It shows how to set the OS upgrade notification.

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake. apt-get dist-upgrade does not upgrade the distribution. Have a look at this page from ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade